# How to type the '3/2' in Latex with different height as shown in the picture?

Tags: fractions

[image]
how to type the fraction 3/2 with different height in Latex as show in the picute

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with the `nicefrac` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign} %
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nicefrac}

\begin{document}

\[ \mathcal O(h^{\nicefrac32} ) \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]